# why cant i update tensorflow 1.7.0 by conda

Tags: tensorflow, conda

I am currently using tensorflow 1.2.1 and I am trying to update to version 1.7.0 using conda, but it is downgraded to 1.1.0. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `tensorflow` version under `conda` package manager is 1.1.0.

1. Try creating a new environment within Anaconda with `conda` virtual environment manager (refer to this [doc](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) for more information):

   ```
   $ conda create -n tensorflow
   ```

   So the subsequent `tensorflow` installation won't mess up with your default Anaconda environment (I personally experienced this).
2. After successfully creating the virtual environment, activate it by:

   ```
   $ source activate tensorflow
   ```

   Your prompt should then change to:

   ```
   (tensorflow) $
   ```
3. To install `tensorflow` version 1.7.0 in the new prompt, use `pip` instead of `conda`:

   ```
   (tensorflow) $ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade TF_PYTHON_URL
   ```

   where TF_PYTHON_URL is the [url of the tensorflow package](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package) with the latest version 1.7.0 (choose according to your `python` version).
4. Note that packages (e.g., `spyder`) you want to use together with `tensorflow` which are not already in the new environment should be installed:

   ```
   (tensorflow) $ conda install spyder
   ```

   This step can be merged with Step 1 by issuing a single command in the **default** prompt:

   ```
   $ conda create -n tensorflow spyder
   ```
5. Every time you work with `tensorflow`, activate the (tensorflow) environment using Step 2, and after you finish, `deactivate` the environment to revert back to the **default** prompt:

   ```
   (tensorflow) $ source deactivate
   ```

Hope these can help :-)

Comment: ``pip install tensorflow==1.7.0`` should work too (after source)